File that has "Begin PGP Message" content?
So we are testing some kind of encryption/decryption of files between us and a client.
I created a pgp key pair and send the public key to client for them to use for encryption..
My questions is when they send the files to us, when we open the file it contains
---Begin PGP Message-- and including all the hash.
Im new to this so my question is that, is the hash that should be seeing from the file we received should be the same as whats inside the public key that we sent them?
Tried to decrypt it with our private key but it fails, also the files they sent us dont have the ".pgp" extension.
I am thinking they are using a different public key to encrypt the files that they send us.

What kind of hash? Do you mean the key fingerprint that it shows as the "recipient"? This is somewhat complex in PGP as your "public key" really has two public keys in it. What software are you using for PGP and how does it display the "hash"?
